# Enable/Disable keydown events based on divs' ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keydown

for div with Id=mainPage I need theses keydown events:

```
$(window).keydown( function(e) {
            if(e.which === 37)
            {
                counter++;
            }

            else if(e.which === 27)
            {
                //DO STH
            }
         });
```

and for another div with id=secondPage I want to have theses events:

```
$(window).keydown( function(e) {
        if(e.which === 65)
        {
            //
        }
});
```

How can I enable and disable keydown events for specific div.

Answer (score 0):

usually a div can not have an keyboard input focus, so it will not receive keystrokes.

you are getting keystrokes on the document. the div's are not involved here. you might want to check if the mouse is over a specific div, when the key event is received through the document. depending on that you can process the key event.

to do this you can use a variable where you save over which div the mouse is. you can change this variable on mouseOver events. than add a condition on keypress wich checks this variable.

another way would be to check the mouse cursor position and compare it to the div's on keypress.